# ldapadduser invalid dn syntax

Tags: ldap

I am trying to host a centralized authentication server using ldap.

I have a working ldap server, and am using phpLDAPadmin to add/delete users.

However, when I try to add user with ldapscripts command "sudo ldapadduser george RA", following the example in  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-auth-config
, it says "Error adding user george to LDAP".

When I look in /var/log/ldapscripts.log, the log message seems obscure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui0j0.png)

I am a newbie to this. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: We will need more informations to help you : configurations, DIT, slapd log, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't familiar enough with ldap and ldapscripts,

I had to edit the config file /etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.conf,
which requires

1. SUFFIX="dc=example,dc=com" : the base domain
2. GSUFFIX="ou=groups" : where the group ou should be
3. USUFFIX="ou=users" : where the users ou should be
4. MSUFFIX="ou=machines": where the machines ou should be

After setting he corresponding organizational units(previously added in LDAP), ldapscripts was fine to use.